# Problem with serving pictures in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create my first site in django and I've run into a problem. I'm trying to serve pictures,but it isn't working correctly. I have it set up in the following way:
In settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/John/Documents/My Dropbox/Infostuff/filmsite/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'localhost:8000/static/'  
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
```

In urls.py:

```
 (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
  {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

It looks like this in the template page:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{a.picture.url}}">
```

And it is parsed to this:

```
<img src="localhost:8000/static/portrets/0000138_Leonardo_D.jpg">
```

When I open the html page it doesn't display the pictures (I get the broken picture icon). If I however go to view the source and copy the above url and past it directly into my browser it *does* load the picture. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Django 1.2. I'm not using Apache yet, because I would first like to get it working in a development environment.

PS: This is the first time I'm asking a question on this site, if I did something wrong, please tell.

Comment: Please post generated source, that makes no sense.

Comment: Just a note: the authors of Django have suggested that it is not the best option to serve up pictures. Have you considered using Apache instead?

Comment: @cwallenpoole it is OK to use this approach for development purposes. For moving to production I agree using nginx or another front end static media server is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/'
```

or

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Django are you using?

Can you post the generated HTML code? if the URL works when you copy and paste in the browser, it might be an html issue as well.

Have you looked at this page yet?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

**Update:**

Can you post the model for a? is a.picture an image field? If so, then you don't need to put the MEDIA_URL in your img src, since it is already an absolute url and it should include the MEDIA_URL already. try removing that and see if it works.

```
<img src='{{a.picture.url}}' />
```

For more info see this page.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: I have. As far as I know I have followed every step on that site. I have also looked at some of the other questions related to this on this site. The interesting thing is, when I'm looking at the source (I'm using Google Chrome) I can click on the produced link and I get taken to a blank page, but if I manually copy the link and paste it in the adress bar it does load the picture.

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MEDIA_URL` should just be `'/static/'` - or, if you must, `'http://localhost:8000/static/'`. Otherwise your browser is interpreting the `localhost` as part of the path, not the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel very stupid...
I had to change

```
MEDIA_URL = 'localhost:8000/static/'
```

to

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/'
```

and then I had change

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{a.picture.url}}">
```

to

```
<img src="{{a.picture.url}}">
```

Thank you for your time.