# Displaying images with in a dictionary loop with Jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2-cli

I can't seem to find the issue here... I can't get the images on the webpage to show up. When I inspect the webpage, the image file location seems to be correct. Anyways, here is my code:
HTML:

```
<body>
{% for key, value in team.items() -%}
    <h1>{{ value }}</h1>
    <img src="{{value}}.png" alt="{{ value }}">
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Python:

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template("index.html",team=okc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: also, the .png files are in the root directory for now...

Comment: Flask attempts to serve static files from a directory named by default `static` in the root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask not serving pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596777/flask-not-serving-pictures)

Comment: No, having the images in a root static folder doesn't work either.

Comment: ok, I got it now... forgot to add the /static onto the img src... thank you guys!